# Can update.zip update-script be used to copy build.prop to an SD card?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, recovery-mode, boot-loop

I made the unfortunate mistake of lowering the dalvik heapsize to 64m and now my tablet is stuck in a bootloop . I've tried to make my own update.zip (including signed ones) and all fail to load in recovery mode, saying "Installation Aborted".

Is there any way to use update.zip to pull build.prop from the device? My computer does not find it on ADB so this is my only option.

**Edit:
I've now got a copy of the original build.prop from the stock ROM. I'm now having trouble getting that back on to the device, as it keeps halting at the extract section. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the permissions I'm using or do I need to specify in the updater-script to delete build.prop?

```
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p6", "/system");
package_extract_dir("system", "/system");
set_perm(0, 0, 0644, "/system/build.prop");
show_progress(0.100000, 0);
unmount("/system");
```

Since my recovery doesn't show output for **ui_print();** I've used **show_progress();** to see how much of the code gets run. It successfully mounts and runs anything, except extracting the package, where it just hangs up and says "Installation Aborted".

Comment: Can you download the ROM for your device? You could (which is read as maybe) dirty install over your ROM (not wiping the system and data, so you apps and info remain intact)……Or you could pull the build.prop and go about it the way you mention in your question.

Comment: I've downloaded the factory ROM, but for some reason I can't put build prop on the device. It keeps returning "Installation Aborted" as before. It can successfully mount the partition and set permissions, but can't copy the file. This is the update.zip that I've been trying: http://cdn.yard.cu.cc/ext/update.zip

Comment: What chmod are you using? Did you consider the dirty install, which would replace the build.prop

Comment: It would set these before modification `set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/system/build.prop");` then set these after modification `set_perm(0, 0, 0644, "/system/build.prop");`. I'm wondering if I need to delete the existing build.prop before attempting to write the new one? I'd expect the old one to be automatically deleted when I attempt to write the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by backing up using the stock recovery, then reflashing the factory firmware. I then went back into stock recovery and restored my user data.

The reason why it wouldn't accept my update.zip files is because they weren't signed by Archos.